# NPOI ArgumentOutOfRangeException on WorkbookFactory.Create

Tags: c#, excel, npoi

I have been using NPOI to read Excel files, and I now need to write out files.  I am trying to use the WorkbookFactory, which doesn't show up in a lot of examples online (doesn't appear in the NPOI examples on CodePlex either).  Here is the code:

```
this.FileStream = new FileStream(
    this.FilePath,
    FileMode.OpenOrCreate,
    FileAccess.ReadWrite);
this.Workbook = WorkbookFactory.Create(
    this.FileStream);
```

When it gets to the second statement, I get an ArgumentOutOfRangeException with the following message: `"Non-negative number required.\r\nParameter name: value".`

Next few lines in the call stack:

```
at System.IO.FileStream.set_Position(Int64 value)
at NPOI.Util.PushbackStream.set_Position(Int64 value)
at NPOI.POIXMLDocument.HasOOXMLHeader(Stream inp)
at NPOI.SS.UserModel.WorkbookFactory.Create(Stream inputStream)
```

Comment: While I am testing, I am trying to write to my desktop.

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't read your post very carefully, the stack and the message clearly points to the Position property being set to a negative number, not that the mode was the out of range.

Comment: Well my eyes are starting to cross from looking at the source code, but I'm pretty sure you need some shell of an `.xls` file to exist for the code to work, and I assume that you are creating the file (because of `FileMode.OpenOrCreate`), so you are getting an exception because the [source code](https://github.com/tonyqus/npoi/blob/master/ooxml/POIXMLDocument.cs) "reads" 4 bytes then rewinds the stream 4 bytes, but for you it is rewinding from 0 to -4 which throws the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [WorkbookFactory](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/WorkbookFactory.html) (link to POI documentation) reads *existing* file data from an input stream, and determines on the fly whether to create an `HSSFWorkbook` or an `XSSFWorkbook` (i.e. whether you are working with XLS or XLSX-like files).

From your code, it seems you are trying to create a *new* file using this class. That is not something the WorkbookFactory can help you with. To *write* files, use the following pattern:

```
var workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
...
using (var fileData = new FileStream(@"path\filename.xlsx", FileMode.Create))
{
  workbook.Write(fileData);
}
```

(In other words, WorkbookFactory is a *class* factory, not a *file* factory :-))